# How to use a negative driver value when scaling?

Tags: drivers, scale

I am working on 2d project and need to scale a plane using driver with a scale variable ,but when the value of driving transform channel is -1 the driver value is still positive and equal 1 . It seems like there is no way in blender to make negative driver value when variable is Scale transform.  **Is it a bug?** How can I get the negative driver value when scaling?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a *Transform Channel*, consider using a *Single Property* when you need to get the exact value of some property:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Expr: 
Instead of var, write -var